# I would like to know how fork works in the following code

Tags: unix, process, fork

In the following code there are no statements after fork. so I would like to know how fork behaves.

```
int main()
{
    fork();
    printf("some print here");
    return 1;
}
```

what happens to child and parent process in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you distinguish between the parent and the child by checking `fork()`'s return code and applying different logic respectively, both the parent and the child will proceed identically by printing the line and exiting.

Comment: parent process id is same as main process id? If so when we exit main, then parent process will also be killed by leaving child alone. does the statement in printf will be printed?

Comment: You are confusing processes with threads. Doing a fork will create a new process with a unique PID that will exist independently of the parent. Threads, on the other hand, belong to the same process, and are all terminated when the process exits.

Comment: Here i did not use any exit function. Still parent and child processes will be killed or they wait indefinitely.

Comment: Both of them will terminate.